# What is the correct way to receive data from a server?

Tags: java, android

Ok so to explain I have server in Java that receives data from a C++ program that I have no control over. So the data is transferred over TCP/IP and the Java server just receives it. The volume of incoming data is huge and it comes at a very fast rate, just imagine a terminal printing loads of lines really fast.. I don't need to get all of it, just as much as I can would be great..

Now I need to send that data to an android device and display it. 
I have no idea what is the best approach to so this.

I am currently pinging the server from my android device every 50ms using an executor. Then I use a handler to display the data. I have already posted a question with code here: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052577/am-i-using-this-handler-and-executor-correctly-android).

Obviously the android app will need to ping it while the app is running so I can't avoid the `while(true)` scenario.

I have read about 100000000 ways to do concurrency in Android, and I do not know what to choose for this.

- I tried simple `Threads`, they were to hard to manage.
- I am now running a `ExecutorService`
- I also read about `ScheduledExecutorService`, but they need a time
  duration right ? My app can be running for 5 hours or 5 minutes or 5
  years.
- I read about HandlerThreads too, but I am not sure they are ideal for
  this scenario.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Would this question maybe be better for here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: It really seems as though you want to be writing a Service in Android.  Within that service there are many options, but if you are constantly waiting for data on the mobile device, then a ServerSocket can be left open to receive data as it comes across until you close it.

Comment: you can use "socket io" or "firebase notification"

Comment: @JaySnayder like I am doing now right ? ExecutorService ? I already have a Socket setup and open, and an InputStreamReader to do all the receiving

Comment: @KarmelinaMichael Is socket.io able to receive such a big amount of data ?

Comment: This question is off-topic here, because of causes opinion based answers. @Jure is right, try there

Comment: @MarcEstrada is it opinion based ? there must be 1 correct answer..

Comment: When a title starts with "What is the best way" this is now opinion based, since there are a lot of solutions to one problem and best or worst, there are opinion based answers

Comment: @MarcEstrada I updated the title then

Comment: @TrtTrt check this answer

Comment: @KarmelinaMichael did you link something ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12978658/9228777