# Set initial delay to a Periodic Work Manager in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I have a `Worker` instance that needs to run every 24 hours which is pretty simple considering the `PeriodicWorkRequest` API. But here's the catch.

If the user initiates the work at say 8 PM, I need the first instance of the work manager to run at 9 AM the next morning and then follow the 24-hour periodic constraint.

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363541/schedule-a-work-on-a-specific-time-with-workmanager/50363613)and I found that the OneTimeWorkRequest API has a `setInitialDelay()` function that can be used but I wasn't able to find anything for the `PeriodicWork` API.

Ther are some hacks for this such as I can use the `OneTimeWork` with the initial delay and then schedule a `PeriodicWork` from there but it's kinda a dirty hack.

Is there any way to do this with just the `PeriodicWorkRequest` API?

Answer (score 17):

On the new version of Work manager ([Version 2.1.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.1.0-alpha02) released on May 16, 2019) PeriodicWorkRequests now support initial delays. You can use the setInitialDelay method on PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder to set an initial delay.

Example:

```
    PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
        WorkerReminderPeriodic.class,
        24,
        TimeUnit.HOURS,
        PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_FLEX_MILLIS,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
      .addTag("send_reminder_periodic")
      .build();


    WorkManager.getInstance()
        .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("send_reminder_periodic", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest);
```

Comment: `setInitialDelay` works weird. When I set a startup period of 15 minutes and the initial delay of 1 minute, the worker starts after 16 minutes. I thought it would immediately (as `OneTimeWorkRequest`), but after 1 minute (and not after 16 minutes). And the subsequent starts will be every 15 minutes.

Comment: @proninyaroslav Periodic work has a minimum interval of 15 minutes and it cannot have an initial delay. MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS is 15 minute. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest#min_periodic_interval_millis

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do a trick with `OneTimeWorkRequest`

Comment: Initial delay cannot be set on PeriodicWorker, initial delay is for oneTimeWorker only

Comment: @SmartAndroidian Can you check the version of Work manager?
it should be Version 2.1.0-alpha02+ to get the setInitialDelay().

Comment: I am using the version `implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1'` and here setInitialDelay() is not there. Sorry I am using stable version of `WorkManager` and not alpha.

Comment: @SmartAndroidian You can use stable version `2.2.0-rc01`. it's there as well.

Comment: A little clarification, this method (setInitialDelay) does not work for a worker on android 23, worker version 2.4.0

Answer (score 12):

**PeriodicWorkRequest** has a nice Builder constructor where you can pass an interval for which the work can execute. You can check the details of the Builder and each parameter [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder#PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20androidx.work.ListenableWorker%3E,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

So, to set an initial delay to your periodic work you can do like this:

```
int hourOfTheDay = 10; // When to run the job
int repeatInterval = 1; // In days

long flexTime = calculateFlex(hourOfTheDay, repeatInterval);

Constraints myConstraints = new Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
        .build();

PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest =
        new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyNiceWorker.class,
                repeatInterval, TimeUnit.DAYS,
                flexTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .setConstraints(myConstraints)
                .build();

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(YOUR_NICE_WORK_TAG,
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
        workRequest);
```

Here is where the magic happens:

```
private long calculateFlex(int hourOfTheDay, int periodInDays) {

    // Initialize the calendar with today and the preferred time to run the job.
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfTheDay);
    cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    // Initialize a calendar with now.
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (cal2.getTimeInMillis() < cal1.getTimeInMillis()) {
        // Add the worker periodicity.
        cal2.setTimeInMillis(cal2.getTimeInMillis() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(periodInDays));
    }

    long delta = (cal2.getTimeInMillis() - cal1.getTimeInMillis());

    return ((delta > PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_FLEX_MILLIS) ? delta
            : PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_FLEX_MILLIS);
}
```

Please be aware that this time is not exact. **WorkManager** may trigger your job at any time in that flex window depending on your constraints, system load, other scheduled jobs, etc.

If you want a precise timing, switch to **AlarmManager**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Docs say that flexTime is ignored on certain API versions (23 for example)... Is there any reasonable solution yet?

Answer (score 4):

With the current alpha release of `WorkManager` (`v1.0.0-alpha07`), i think it's not possible to set initial delay for the `PeriodicWorkReqeust`. May be we'll get some API in next releases.

For the time being, as you said, you can use a `OneTimeWork` request setup with initial delay, which will then en-queue a `PeriodicWork` request to WorkManager.

I would say it a hack but not that much dirty.

Comment: Yeah, that's my current strategy. I was just wondering if there was any straightforward way.

Comment: @qasim, have some codes, how to achieve this ?