# How to do something at a specified date and time with Android AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to start work to perform at 8:00 am on a specific date. Is there any way to perform this task using `AlarmManager`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schedule a work on a specific time with WorkManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363541/schedule-a-work-on-a-specific-time-with-workmanager)

Comment: Alarm Manager is a better option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use AlarmManager instead of work manager. Work Manager is made for things which are deferrable and guaranteed, meaning it can be done later and not crucially now. To have some background service which does work that has to happen at an exact time and is guaranteed consider using [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager).

There's also this StackOverflow answer:
[Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363541/schedule-a-work-on-a-specific-time-with-workmanager)

There's no need to waste time by trying to implement work manager for your task.

**Edit:** My bad, the example was an old link. Messy it is!